# Quiz App Programing

Tags: java, android

I am working on a quiz app and I need help writing code for the quiz part of the app. See I have this app that I am creating where the user can add a list of questions (true or false) and then take the quiz. Thi quiz has to tell the user if they are right or wrong and then a next button to move forward. I need help on how to get the question from the list the user enter and use it in the quiz. here is the code I have so far....

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class QuizQuestionsActivity {
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Array mAnswerKey;
    private int mCurrentIndex;
    private static QuizQuestionsActivity mQuestion;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mAnswerKey[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestion.setText(question);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_question);

        mQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);

            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mAnswerKey.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        updateQuestion();
    }
    /**
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }
    */
}
```

}

Comment: Are there any parts other than the quiz part of a quiz app? :)

Comment: Yes there is more.

Comment: I was joking.  You need to explain what the problem is, exceptions etc.  SO isnt fond of reading big walls of code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is just for a UI for taking the test. So I assume you need help figuring out a check-list to complete your program:

1- You mentioned, the user can add list of questions. If you want to get and store these questions in runtime, you need to create a new Activity to do that

2- You have three options for storing your question answer pairs:

- in any collections you seem fit like `HashMap`. This would then be a local thing and don't store anything so if the application get destroyed, you need to insert your questions and answers again
- store the data in collections and store them as `JSON` format in `SharedPreferences`. you can store the list in `onPause` and restore it in `onResume` for example
- store your data in `sqlite` database which gives you more flexibility but needs more codes

3- You need to retrieve the list of questions answers pair from the collection or database and implement a logic (like random) to display a question (probably in your `updateQuestion()` method)

4- Check the correctness of the answers and keeping a score (?) which can be done in your `checkAnswer()`